# Can a server process data without client request?

Tags: python, flask

I recently got into Flask web programming and built a shopping website fro scratch as an engineering school project, however I got lost when it came to product ranking etc.
I had this idea for a dating website as an exercise but as I see it the server will have to run its own calculations to rank different possible couples in terms of compatibility, which is really the interesting part of the project.
I don't really see these ranking calculations only being processed upon request as thay may take some time, but maybe I am highly underestimating SQL processing speed. **I believe the data processing and calculations need to be run continuously on the server. If this is in fact continuous server data processing, how would I go about doing that?**
I hope the question makes sense, my English tends to be a bit dodgy as I don't live in an English-speaking country.
Regards

Comment: Up to Flask 0.10 you can use [this extension](https://flask-script.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) from 0.11 on you can write a [custom management command](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/cli/#custom-commands)

Comment: A client request is just an event that kicks off some code. You can write your own code and execute it at will. There are so many ways to do this, it's hard to know where to start. You don't *need* to run this through flask either. It can be a simple script that processes data. How you do this will depend a lot on where your code and data are hosted.

Comment: Thank you so much, so if I understand correctly it involves running another program than just 'flask run' in terminal, another program at the same time, dedicated to processing the data - and that could for example be written within the flask framework using commands as Klaus explained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need background tasks without client requests, you can go for Celery (https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/periodic-tasks.html). You can assign works to this server and it will run in background without intervening Django server.

Comment: Very interesting! Had a look and seems to solve the problem! Do you know it this also works with flask?

Comment: It works with Flask too, celery is another server , so we need to run flask and celery in separate server and connect each other.